# jQuery - Multiple elements with same class - need to hide one if and only if it contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish - the HTML:

```
<div id="section">
    <div class="test-row">
        <div class="row-copy-options">
            <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 1</b></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test-row">
        <div class="row-copy-options">
            <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 2</b></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test-row">
        <div class="row-copy-options">
            <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 3</b></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test-row">
        <div class="row-copy-options">
            <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 4</b></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test-row">
        <div class="row-copy-options">
            <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 5</b></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, any section that contains the heading "Test Heading 2" - hide that specific test-row div. That's what I'm trying to do with jQuery, but so far not having any luck.

Comment: Include your jQuery code also that you have done so far

Comment: I will remember to do that next time.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. Loop through all `h4`elements, check for `Test Heading 2`, get parent div with class `test-row` and hide it.

**Edit: Using `map` function**

```
$(function () {
   $("#section h4").map(function(i,el){ $(el).text() == "Test Heading 2" ? $(el).closest(".test-row").hide() : el });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
   $("#section h4").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == "Test Heading 2") $(this).closest(".test-row").hide();
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
 <div class="test-row">
  <div class="row-copy-options">
   <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 1</b></h4>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="test-row">
  <div class="row-copy-options">
   <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 2</b></h4>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="test-row">
  <div class="row-copy-options">
   <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 3</b></h4>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="test-row">
  <div class="row-copy-options">
   <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 4</b></h4>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="test-row">
  <div class="row-copy-options">
   <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 5</b></h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's like this:

```
//to hide single item 
$("div.row-copy-options:has(h4:contains('Test Heading 1'))").hide();

//to hide multiple items
$("div.row-copy-options:has(h4:contains('Test Heading 1'),h4:contains('Test Heading 2'))").hide();
```

Comment: While just code is acceptable, it's always better to explain **why** the code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/enm7sw0f/

```js
$('.test-row').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('b:contains("Test Heading 2")').length)
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
  <div class="test-row">
    <div class="row-copy-options">
      <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 1</b></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test-row">
    <div class="row-copy-options">
      <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 2</b></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test-row">
    <div class="row-copy-options">
      <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 3</b></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test-row">
    <div class="row-copy-options">
      <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 4</b></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test-row">
    <div class="row-copy-options">
      <h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 5</b></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Loop through all the `.test-row` div and check for the content, if matches then hide the div.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

your html

```
<div id="section">
<div class="test-row">
<div class="row-copy-options">
<h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 1</b></h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="test-row">
<div class="row-copy-options">
<h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 2</b></h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="test-row">
<div class="row-copy-options">
<h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 3</b></h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="test-row">
<div class="row-copy-options">
<h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 4</b></h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="test-row">
<div class="row-copy-options">
<h4 class="text-capitalize"><b>Test Heading 5</b></h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

First approach using h4 tagname

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h4:contains('Test Heading')").hide();
});
```

Second approach using h4 tagname with class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h4.text-capitalize:contains('Test Heading')").hide();
});
```

so many ways we can do